# Bundler requires different ruby version on deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I defined ruby version 2.0.0-p645 in `.ruby_version` file

`cap production deploy` stops with bundler error:

```
INFO [11dd01a8] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /var/www/p4-site/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on p4-ocean
DEBUG [11dd01a8] Command: cd /var/www/p4-site/releases/20160206090913 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /var/www/p4-site/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [11dd01a8]        ruby-2.0.0-p481 is not installed.
DEBUG [11dd01a8]        To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p481'
DEBUG [11dd01a8]        /usr/local/rvm/scripts/set: line 19: exec: bundle: not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
```

Gemfile doesn't contain `ruby` command

`.bundle/config` file contains

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

Where does bundler store ruby version 2.0.0-p481 ?

Comment: I believe the correct version file is `.ruby-version`, but which version is defined in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: So do i, but why bundler wants p481?

Comment: may be it is default version for capistrano, grep the `p481` over your sources to make sure that you havnt set it up in else place: `grep 'p481' -r`

Comment: it turned out that I specified .ruby_version in separate branch, but deployed from master with old ruby version.

Comment: Something to remember is that if you're firing bundler from bash, bash won't have the ruby version denotation that your `Gemfile` does.